# How can a Table Query be performed on Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, nestjs, azure-table-storage

### Current behavior

I would like to query the Azure Table Storage Database using a Table Query. There isn't any documentation here on how that can be achieved. My approach (probably wrong) has been to do the following:

```
import { TableQuery } from 'azure-storage';
import { Repository } from '@nestjs/azure-database';

export class SomeService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(EntitySchema)
        private readonly entityRepo: Repository<EntitySchema>
    ) {}
    
   async findSpecific(entityProperty: string): Promise<EntitySchema> {
       const query = new TableQuery();
       return await this.entityRepo.findAll(query.where(`property == ${entityPropery}`));
   }
}
```

The error I am getting from this is: `The requested operation is not implemented on the specified resource.`

### Expected behavior

The query returns the defined results.

### Environment

```
Nest version: 8.2.3
<!-- Check whether this is still an issue in the most recent Nest version -->
 
For Tooling issues:
- Node version: v17.2.0
- Platform:  MacOS

Others:
<!-- Anything else relevant?  Operating system version, IDE, package manager, ... -->
```

Comment: Can you try by changing the following code `property == ${entityPropery}` with `property eq ${entityPropery}`?

Comment: @GauravMantri good thinking but no good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is over a year later, but in case someone else is DuckDuckGo-ing this. I believe this is the syntax you're looking for and, I agree, the documentation is lacking.

```js
async findByEmail(email: string): Promise<AzureTableStorageResultList<Profile>> {
    const query = new TableQuery();
    return await this.profileRepository.findAll(query.where('email == ?', email));
}
```